# How do I submit a bug to Tracker, MantisBT, or Trac programatically?

Tags: bug-tracking, trac, mantis, tracker

I've got a program that I've been working on at home for a while, and I decided finally to throw it up on SourceForge.  SourceForge offers Tracker, MantisBT, or Trac for bug tracking.

My app already has a "Sorry, an error occurred" dialog, but I'd like to add a "Complain about it" button that will submit a bug to my bug tracker.  Has anyone tried to do this with Tracker?  Can you submit anonymous bugs via a query string interface, or something along those lines?  Or, if Tracker can't do it, how about MantisBT?  Or Trac?

Answer (score 2):

Programmatic access:

- Mantis has a [SOAP interface](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php);
- Trac has an [XML-RPC interface](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin).

If your application happens to be built on Eclipse, you can use the existing Mylyn plugins - they're both offered with 1-click install since version 3.2  ([reference](http://tasktop.com/blog/eclipse/tasktop-15-mylyn-32-and-new-connectors-released-for-eclipse-galileo)).

Answer (score 1):

Also, Mantis 1.1.x (and perhaps later 1.2.x) has a php script (core/checkin.php) that can be called from a post-commit hook when the repo and mantis live on the same host.  You just need to provide the glue for the hook, e.g. bash, and either commit all notes as a user defined 'vcs' userame or make a small modification to the php to determine the user making the commit.

In the later 1.1.x versions there is a checkincurl.php that will address usage when mantis and the repo are not collocated.